# Do you remember me? Who or what am I?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, video-games

I've often wondered how many would have succeeded without me?
Do you, guys, easily succumb to the temptation?
Do you summon me straight away, instead of being true to the spirit of the real fighters?
Question is - should I have been revealed to the world in the first place?
Doesn't it spoil the pleasure of achieving the goal without me?

Who or what am I?

Further to some comment, I've changed one of the lines cause I think it causes a big of ambiguity.

And, also, the answer IS in the question.

> Without me a lot of fighters would have been 'doomed'.

Comment: I will add one more tag in one hour if nobody has spotted the answer by then.

Comment: Yes, at the moment, I think this question is a bit too broad, as all the current answers can fit your riddle.

Comment: i think i know what he wants but i have no culture o knoledge enough. im trying to search it but didnt find anything relevant yet

Comment: OK, I've added the 'revealing'-tag.

Comment: Is it about one video-game or video-games in general ?

Comment: @BaptisteViloin Yes, it is, and there is already a correct answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it is

> God mode

Because

> Each of the first letter spells 'IDDQD' which is god mode for the game [Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_(1993_video_game)).

*I found it thanks to the tag [video-game](/questions/tagged/video-game) and the hint 'doomed'.*

Comment: awwww almost. ahahah i still was searching "fighters" related

Comment: doom was one of my favorite game, so after hint 'IDDQD' rung the bell :D, I hope this is it!

Comment: @smriti YES! You've got it!

Comment: see? i needed more videogame culture... i just played the new Doom  and a few hours lol

Comment: I first thought of "cheat", so not far from the real answer xD

Answer (score 9):

Are you

> A hint

Do you, guys, easily succumb to the temptation?
Do you summon me straight away, instead of being true to the spirit of the real fighters?

> When someone finds a riddle too complicated, he is likely to ask for a hint quickly.

Question is - should I have revealed myself to the world in the first place?

> If OP post a hint in his post, the riddle might be too easy.

Doesn't it spoil the pleasure of achieving the goal without me?

> Solving a riddle without any hint is a bit more pleasuring than with hints.

Comment: i was thinking about "cheating"  lol

Comment: @lois6b you are going in the right direction!

Comment: oh! so, this answer is not valid? :O

Comment: @lois6b I'm afraid it is not.

Answer (score 6):

**Comments**
I think he wants a specific videogame with secret that with it, the game is easier. He also say "the answer is in the question " so Real Fighters game?

Regarding the comment in the IAmInPLS anser, i think the answer can be:

> Cheat codes in games

Do you, guys, easily succumb to the temptation?
Do you summon me straight away, instead of being true to the spirit of the real fighters?

> When someone struggles in a game, can activate cheat codes or commands to make it easy

Doesn't it spoil the pleasure of achieving the goal without me?

> Completing a game is more pleasant without tricks

Comment: Again, you are in the right direction but you have to be more specific than that.

Comment: you are very, very close, just be a bit more specific. Look at the question.

Comment: i knew the videogame thing but dont know too much about videogames lol . just the recent ones (and pokemon) . so the "remember me?" probably not xD

Comment: I've added a hint and let google be your friend.

Comment: I thought this was the answer. I thought 'remember me' was about less games having them now

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> Trainer

Do you, guys, easily succumb to the temptation?

Do you summon me straight away, instead of being true to the spirit of the real fighters?

> no body tries any game with trainer at first

Question is - should I have revealed myself to the world in the first place?

> No game reveals trainer for itself.

Doesn't it spoil the pleasure of achieving the goal without me?

> Its no fun playing game with trainer.

Regards.

Comment: There is already a valid answer.

Comment: I was thinking about alternative possibility satisfying answer to the question.